# Uploading multiple images php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to upload an item, accompanied with multiple images of the item which should be stored in a mysql database and a folder "uploads" as well.
The code for inserting the item works well but the code for uploading the image does not execute. I have 2 tables images and properties with a one to many relationship.

```
 <?php
require('DBconnect.php');
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // removes backslashes
$title = stripslashes($_REQUEST['title']);
$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$title); 

$area = stripslashes($_REQUEST['area']);
$area = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$area);

$price = stripslashes($_REQUEST['price']);
$price = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$price);

    $query = "INSERT into `properties` (propertyTitle, propertyArea, propertyPrice)
    VALUES ('$title', '$area', '$price')";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
    $prpId= mysqli_insert_id($connection);
    if($result){
        echo "Property registered successfully";

         $targetFolder = "uploads";
        //the code below is not executed by the server. Reasons for which i have no clue
    foreach($_FILES as $file => $fileArray)
    {

        if(!empty($fileArray['name']) && $fileArray['error'] == 0)
        {
            $getFileExtension = pathinfo($fileArray['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);;

            if(($getFileExtension =='jpg') || ($getFileExtension =='jpeg') || ($getFileExtension =='png') || ($getFileExtension =='gif'))
            {
                if ($fileArray["size"] <= 5000000) 
                {
                    $breakImgName = explode(".",$fileArray['name']);
                    $imageOldNameWithOutExt = $breakImgName[0];
                    $imageOldExt = $breakImgName[1];

                    $newFileName = strtotime("now")."-".str_replace(" ","-",strtolower($imageOldNameWithOutExt)).".".$imageOldExt;


                    $targetPath = $targetFolder."/".$newFileName;



                    if (move_uploaded_file($fileArray["tmp_name"], $targetPath)) 
                    {
                        $qry = "INSERT INTO images (image, propertyId)
                        VALUES ('".$newFileName."', '".$prpId."')";                        
                        $rs  = mysqli_query($connection, $qry); 
                    }
               }
        }

      }
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Your code expects the `$_FILES` array to look like `$_FILES[0]['name']` while it actually looks like `$_FILES['name'][0]`. Here's the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: Hi Magnus. However, when i place the code for uploading images on a separate file it works well

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
   enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to the form and it worked.